# Dependency scoped "compile" not included in assembly

Tags: maven-2, scope, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I have the following dependency specified in my project's POM:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

My project itself has to be the child of another POM. And in that one, the following is defined:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.client</groupId>
   <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
   <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

When I now assembly my program, it seems that the "provided" scope of the parent POM overrides the scope of my project, since the `jbossall-client.jar` is not included in my assembly. Although it seems illogical to me, maybe it's [this feature](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) taking effect here.

Do you know a way to include the dependency in my assembly without touching the parent POM?

---

**Edit:**
Output of `mvn dependency-tree` (Updated!):

```
[dependency:tree]
com.myproject:myproject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- com.myproject-commons:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
|  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
|  +- sv.seucc:seucc-unicode:jar:1.0.1.5:compile
|  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.2:compile
|  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.1:compile
|  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
+- com.myproject-interfaces2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- com.myproject-service-commons:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
+- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.1:compile
+- com.myproject-modules:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
\- org.jboss.client:jbossall-client:jar:4.2.3.GA:compile
```

---

**Edit 2:** Here the dependency part of my assembly XML.

```
 <dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
   <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
  </dependencySet>
 </dependencySets>
```

---

**Edit 3:** Here are the files in the *lib* folder of my obtained assembly.

```
commons-io-1.3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
seucc-unicode-1.0.1.5.jar
spring-2.5.6.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
xstream-1.2.1.jar
myproject-commons-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
myproject-modules-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
myproject-service-commons-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
myproject-interfaces2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

---

**Edit 4:** For the **answer** to this question see the final comments of the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both dependencies don't have the same `groupId` so nothing get overridden here, they are treated as distinct artifacts. But I wonder how things work in your child pom (since the `jbossall-client` doesn't have any version). Do you have a `dependencyManagement` section?

Anyway, to "debug" this kind of problem, use `mvn dependency:tree` in your child project (and post the output if you need more help).

---

**Update:** The above was my answer to the initial question and does not reflect the current state of the question.

For the sake of clarity, the key of the final solution was to declare a `<scope>compile</scope>` (which defaults to `runtime`) in the `dependencySet` element of the assembly descriptor. See the comments for all details.

#### See also

- [8.5.4.3. Including and Excluding Dependencies by Scope](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-output-algorithm.html#assemblies-sect-include-by-scope)

Comment: When I remove the `<scope>` tag from the jbossall-client in my child pom and then check in Eclipse -> Dependency Hierachy, the jbossall-client's scope is marked as `provided`. Therefore I assumed that it inherits the `<scope>` value from it's parent.
I haven't found any `dependencyManagement` section in one of the poms. Where else could I look for?
I've appended the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to my original post. See above please.

Comment: @BernhardV: You're very likely inheriting it, but not from where where you think you are. As I said, the dependencies you're showing don't have the same `groupId` and as you can see, you get version 4.2.3, not 4.2.2. Anyway, the dependency tree looks fine and the jbossall-client is there with a compile scope. There must be something else wrong somewhere. Can you show the content of your assembly descriptor and the content of the obtained assembly? Actually, a simplified pom allowing to reproduce would be nice.

Comment: I've found out from where I inherit the jbossall-client.jar. In my Eclipse workspace I've checked out an older version of the parent pom than it was specified in the child pom. I've corrected my first post and now the groupId is the same. I had to specify the version too. The strange thing is now, that it is included in my assembly, although I haven't provided a `<scope>` tag. :-\ I'm not sure if I should be happy about this.

Comment: Turns out that I haven't updated the parent's pom version in my child pom. Now I've got the same problem as in the beginning. In the parent the scope is provided, but in the child the scope is compile. But it seems that the parent overrides the child, because it is not included in my assembly. :-(

Comment: I've now added my assembly descriptor and the files in the lib directory to my entry post.

Comment: @BernhardV: I need the up to date output of `dependency:tree` (and just in case, maybe have a look at [8.5.4.3. Including and Excluding Dependencies by Scope](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-output-algorithm.html#assemblies-sect-include-by-scope) in the Maven Book).

Comment: I've added `<scope>compile</scope>` to the `dependencySet` in the assembly xml and now it seems to work! The default value is runtime. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and solved it by adding a 2nd dependencySet of scope provided, BUT this only worked once we upgraded to version 2.2.1 of the assembly plugin.